Принтер не печатает, linux ubuntu
Если вкратце. Система принтер видит, принтер в работающем состоянии. При попытке распечаать что-либо сначала пишет о начале печати, потом через 1-2 секнды о том, что печать успешно завершена. Только принтер печатать и не начинал. Модель - epson L210.

в ремонт сдавать пробовали?
